# Best way to pass parameters to SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: pyspark, airflow

So far i have been providing all required variables in the "application" field in the file itself this however feels a bit hacky.
So for example:

```
spark_clean_store_data = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id="my_task_id",
    application="/path/to/my/dags/scripts/clean_store_data.py",
    conn_id="spark_conn",
    dag=dag,
    )
```

So the question is what is the most airflowy/proper way to provide `SparkSubmitOperator` with parameters like input data and or output files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/_api/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit/index.html), you might consider using the following parameters of the `SparkSubmitOperator`

- `files` : a comma-separated string that allows you to upload files in the working directory of each executor
- `application_args` : a list of string that allows you to pass arguments to the application